# CMD to execute BAT to execute CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a script which searches a directory for a specific type of file then use that file in a command. The .bat file is executed from a cmd and the directory is passed as a parameter.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set real_parent_path_unformated=%1%
set real_parent_path=!real_parent_path_unformated:%%20= ^%!

for /R "%real_parent_path%\" %%S in (*.pts) do (
    set /a ptscount+=1
    set ptsfile=!ptsfile! "%%S"
    if !ptscount!==1 (
        START "run PTGUI" /wait cmd.exe /c "S:\Production\CrushFTP7_PC\modules\PTGUI\ptgui.exe -batch -x !ptsfile!"
        set ptscount=0
        set "ptsfile="
    )
)
exit
```

real_parent_path_unformated= directory passed from the server

real_parent_path= directory with %%20 removed

ptsfile= full file path example from log:

"S:\Production\incoming\CHI_TEST_City_Newsstand_4018_North_Cicero_Avenue_60641__\PANO_\1\RAW\DSC_0529_PANORAMA.pts"

However, the program does not execute, giving me this error:

**SHGetFolderPath failed: The specified path is invalid. (0xa1)**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you sure this produces the needed result `set real_parent_path=!real_parent_path_unformated:%%20= ^%!` .Could you echo the `!real_parent_path!` and see if its ok?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you've provided us with a path that doesn't contain the potential target-strings-for-substitution ("%%20", "%20" or <kbd>space</kbd>) and we've no idea whether you are supplying the string to the procedure "quoted" or you've simply taken `the actual string you are passing` and quoted it in preference to hilighting it.

So - a few guesses.

```
set real_parent_path_unformated=%1%
```

The terminal `%` is incorrect. A parameter `n` is referred to as `%n`. If you want to remove the anclosing quotes, then use `~n`.

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

In your code, you may have quotes being set as **part of the value being assigned** hence, if `real_parent_path` contains the value `"a big string"` then

```
for /R "%real_parent_path%\" %%S in (*.pts) do (
```

will be interpreted as

for /R ""a big string"\" %%S in (*.pts) do (

which may or may not be delivering the error. It's on your machine, not mine, so testing can only be done in theory.

Next problem is

```
set real_parent_path=!real_parent_path_unformated:%%20= ^%!
```

For the reasons stated above, this is better as

```
set "real_parent_path=!real_parent_path_unformated:%%20= ^%!"
```

But what you're substituting for what is unclear.

- `%` escapes `%` so `%%` becomes `%`
- `^` does not escape `%`

It's perfectly OK to use <kbd>Space</kbd> in the string-substitution command, if that's what you want.

And finally, it may be that `ptsfile` itself contains quotes after processing, so `"cmd /c...!ptsfile!" would result in`"cmd /c..."contents_of_variable_ptsfile"" - probably not what you'd prefer.

```
START "run PTGUI" /wait "S:\Production\CrushFTP7_PC\modules\PTGUI\ptgui.exe" -batch -x !ptsfile!
```

(where the quotes around `S:\Production\CrushFTP7_PC\modules\PTGUI\ptgui.exe` are optional since the string contains no separators) should execute the required program.